# No module named cy_yolo_findboxes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, yolo

I'm trying to use Yolo for object detection, and I get this error

```
File "/home/canok/Desktop/YOLO2/darkflow/darkflow/net/yolo/predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
ImportError: No module named cy_yolo_findboxes
```

I've already install cython :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first use this  python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace

than python3 flow --model cfg/yolo.cfg --load yolo.weights --demo record.avi --saveVideo

Answer (score 0):

Try building the cython_utils ind darkflow folder

```
cd ./cython_utils
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
cd ..
```

Comment: thnx a lot friend